# How to create a routable modal in react without using the location state?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have referred the examples available on these sites:
[React Router](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/modal-gallery)
[LogRocket](https://blog.logrocket.com/building-a-modal-module-for-react-with-react-router/)

I want to create a routable modal component without using the location state.

Comment: Please elaborate more on the topic.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.